# Phonegap CLI on linux doesn't do anything

Tags: linux, cordova, command-line-interface

I've installed the phonegap cli with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

When I then type

```
phonegap create testApp
```

It doesn't do anything, it doesn't output anything, no error messages. I've tried reinstalling it, installing cordova, but nothing.

I'm working on kubuntu 13.10

Any ideas?

Comment: The [phonegap googlegroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: What does `phonegap -V create testApp` give?

Comment: Make sure you have Java & Ant installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was doing:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
npm update npm -g
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

And then after that:

```
sudo npm -g remove phonegap
sudo npm -g install phonegap
```

After that phonegap started to work like a charm...

This was mostly taken from [these](http://julianhigman.com/blog/2013/10/17/notes-on-setting-up-phonegap-on-ubuntu-for-android-app-development/) notes

I have ubuntu 13.10

Comment: thanks alot! it worked. only change I did was "sudo npm update npm -g" instead of "npm update npm -g"